# Bind body and uri http parameters into Spring controller method parameters

Tags: spring, parameters, bind

Hy,

I have the next controller method in Spring:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="indicadores/{entUsuario}/{codUsuario}/{idCliente}",    method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
@ResponseBody
public IndicadoresBean getIndicadoresPlanBasicoBean(   
        @RequestBody InvestmentProposalGroupingResponse investmentProposalGroupingBean,
        IndicadoresPlanBasicoRequest request,           
        BindingResult validationResult,
        HttpServletResponse response) {......... }
```

But when I send a request I get :

"Required request body content is missing: org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod$HandlerMethodParameter".

1. If I change the verb to POST it works but I need it works with GET
2. I need to fill in the request body json in the parameter investmentProposalGroupingBean and uri parameters in parameter request. Is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body.

Comment: Thanks. I have been able to bind an http body into a java bean in a spring method controller, using GET!. But I used spring boot and now I dont use it and the only way is use POST.